Noether current for Yang-Mills theory in the absence of scalar field
The theory with an arbitrary compact gauge group $G$ is given. And global transformations are valid (see below)
$$
A_{\mu}\mapsto{A^{'}_{\mu}={\omega}A_{\mu}\omega^{-1}}
$$
also $\omega \in G$ and it does not depend on $x$
A Lagrangian looks like
$$
L =-\frac{1}{4} F^a_{\mu\nu}F^{a\mu\nu}
$$
where $F^a_{\mu\nu}$ is a tensor of chromo-electromagnetic field strength in Yang-Mills theory.
How can I calculate the Noether current considering that scalar field is absent?

The Noether current of what symmetry? There is not just one Noether current. Also $F^a_{\mu\nu}$ is non-Abelian, the EM field strenght has no internal "a" index

@LolloBoldo Oh! My fault, I apologize. Added symmetry conditions and question has been updated! Also the use of a tensor $F$ with such indices is also an additional condition

Show your work producing the current. What’s this talk about scalar fields?

Hint: convince the reader you understand the infinitesimal global color transformation of the gluon field you write in terms of adjoint indices. Show the variation of your Lagrangian w.r.t. gradients of these fields.
